# add seller to the pos screen in odoo

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I am working on odoo project and I want to add a button in the POS screen to add employee as seller with a code
and I wrote this code for model

```
class PosOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.order'

    seller_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Salesperson', help="You can see salesperson here")
```

and this code in the level of javascript

```
odoo.define("pos_custom.AddSellerButton", function(require) {
    "use strict";

    const PosComponent = require("point_of_sale.PosComponent");
    const ProductScreen = require("point_of_sale.ProductScreen");
    const Registries = require("point_of_sale.Registries");
    const { useListener } = require("@web/core/utils/hooks");

    class AddSellerButton extends PosComponent {

        setup() {
            super.setup();
            useListener("click", this.add_seller_button_click);
        }

        async add_seller_button_click() {
            try {
                const employees = await this._fetchAllEmployees();
                console.log("Fetched Employees:", employees);
                const selectedEmployee = await this._showSelectionPopup(employees);
                if (selectedEmployee){
                   this._setSellerId(selectedEmployee);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching employees:", error);
                this.showPopup("ErrorPopup", {
                                   title: this.env._t("Error fetching employees"),
                                   body: this.env._t(error)
                               });
            }
        }

        async _fetchAllEmployees() {
            const posConfigId = this.env.pos.config.id;
            const response = await this.rpc({
                model: 'hr.employee',
                method: 'search_read',
                args: [[
                        ['is_seller', '=', true],
                        ['store_id', '=', posConfigId],
                        ]],
            });
            const records = response.result || response;
            return records;
        }

        async _showSelectionPopup(employees) {
            if (!employees || employees.length === 0) {
                console.warn("No employees found.");
                this.showPopup("ErrorPopup", {
                                   title: this.env._t("Stop"),
                                   body: this.env._t("No employees found.")
                               });
                return;
            }

            const employeeList = employees.map(employee => ({
                'id': employee.id,
                'label': employee.name,
                'item': employee,
            }));

            const { confirmed, payload: selectedOption } = await this.showPopup("SelectionPopup", {
                title: "Select",
                body: "Select One of these",
                list: employeeList,
            });

            if (confirmed) {
                console.log("Selected Employee:", selectedOption);
            }
            return confirmed ? selectedOption : null;
        }

        _setSellerId(selectedEmployee) {
            console.log("Employee Data :" ,selectedEmployee);
            if (selectedEmployee) {
                const order = this.env.pos.get_order();
                order.salesperson = [parseInt(selectedEmployee.id), selectedEmployee];
            }
        }
    }

    AddSellerButton.template = "AddSellerButton";
    ProductScreen.addControlButton({
        component: AddSellerButton,
        position: ["before", "OrderlineCustomerNoteButton"],
        condition: function() {
            return true;
        },
    });

    Registries.Component.add(AddSellerButton);

    return AddSellerButton;
});
```

and

```
odoo.define('pos_custom.Order', function(require) {
    'use strict';
    const { Order } = require('point_of_sale.models');
    const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');

    const SalesPersonOrder = (Order) => class SalesPersonOrder extends Order {

        constructor(obj, options) {
            console.log("test 1");
            super(obj, options)
            if (options.json) {
                console.log("test 2");
                this.salesperson = options.json.salesperson;
                console.log(this.salesperson);
            }
        }

        init_from_JSON(json) {
            super.init_from_JSON(json)
            this.salesperson = json.salesperson;
        }

        export_as_JSON() {
           console.log("test 3");
            if (this.salesperson) {
                var seller_id = this.salesperson[0]
            } else {
                var seller_id = ''
            }
            console.log("test 4" , seller_id);
            var x = _.extend(super.export_as_JSON(...arguments), {
                seller_id: seller_id
            });
            console.log("x is :", x);
            return x
        }
    }
    Registries.Model.extend(Order, SalesPersonOrder);
});
```

and all the code working fine except, saving the selected employee id in the seller_id field
and I tried many times to save this without anything

Comment: Please refer this forum: https://www.odoo.com/id_ID/forum/help-1/how-to-store-and-add-a-field-in-pos-product-screen-odoo-15-235381